# Problem with mxEditor and xml configuration file

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph

I'm trying to use mxGraph editor. I read the examples and try to understand it. But I can't. From the the tutorial page, in the "port.html" file, they describe the way that they load an xml file for configure an editor. To sum up, they have this configuration file:

```
<mxEditor>
    <mxDefaultKeyHandler as="keyHandler">
        <add as="8" action="collapse"/>
        <add as="13" action="expand"/>
        <add as="33" action="exitGroup"/>
        <add as="34" action="enterGroup"/>
        <add as="35" action="refresh"/>
        <add as="36" action="home"/>
        <add as="37" action="selectPrevious"/>
        <add as="38" action="selectParent"/>
        <add as="40" action="selectChild"/>
        <add as="39" action="selectNext"/>
        <add as="46" action="delete"/>
        <add as="65" control="1" action="selectAll"/>
        <add as="90" control="1" action="undo"/>
        <add as="89" control="1" action="redo"/>
        <add as="88" control="1" action="cut"/>
        <add as="67" control="1" action="copy"/>
        <add as="86" control="1" action="paste"/>
        <add as="71" control="1" action="group"/>
        <add as="85" control="1" action="ungroup"/>
        <add as="113" action="edit"/>       
        <add as="123" action="showProperties"/>
        <add as="107" action="zoomIn"/>
        <add as="109" action="zoomOut"/>
    </mxDefaultKeyHandler>
</mxEditor>
```

And in port.html, they put this :

```
var editor = new mxEditor();
var graph = editor.graph;
var model = graph.getModel();
editor.setGraphContainer(container);
var config = mxUtils.load('editors/config/keyhandler-commons.xml').getDocumentElement();
editor.configure(config);
```

Then, when I try to execute any oh this bindings with the associate action on my canvas, it doesn't work, and I realy don't know why.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I know I see that pretty late, but what I would do is:

```
var config = mxUtils.load('editors/config/keyhandler-commons.xml').getDocumentElement();
var editor = new mxEditor(config);
```

You may also not have to query for the graph in order to direct to your `container`.
mxGraph will do that for you if, in your config file, you have specified:

```
<ui>
  <add as="graph" element="container"/>
  ...
</ui>
```